# How old is the use of "L minus" to denote the number of days before launch?

Tags: launch, terminology, time, inspiration-4

In the SpaceX Inspiration4 Launch broadcast at about `T-01:31:05` (91 minutes before launch) the term "L minus five" is used. While "T-minus" is a standard phrase in use since the early days of spaceflight, I've never heard "L minus" or "L plus" used before.

**Question:** How old is the use of "L minus" to denote the number of days before launch?

> So the procedure for picking the launch window is actually a little bit different.
>
> We reserved a couple of days -- a couple of *twenty four hour days* for the mission, **but had to wait until L minus five, or five days before the first launch day that was selected** to narrow it down to twelve hours. And then after that, we waited until **L minus three** to select the five hour window that we have today.
>
> And then we have four opportunities in each of those launch windows about an hour apart, to lift off.
>
> So it's a very unique case; so we really just knew just three days ago **what the T zero in the launch window would be.**

---

[SpaceX Inspiration 4 Launch broadcast at about T-01:31:05 (91 minutes before launch) where the term "L minus five" is used](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3pv01sSq44w)

[image]

Comment: It was standard in the shuttle program. L minus was the wall clock time before launch, T minus was the countdown time before launch. So L minus was T minus plus the built in holds.

Comment: It's still used. I remember hearing it on several launches recently. Might have been Antares and Arianespace. We normally don't hear it on SpaceX because the do load-and-go, and thus don't have the possibility for holds.